# Не устанавливается приложение на Genymotion

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, genymotion

После обновления Android Studio к версии 2.3 не устанавливается никакое приложение на Genymotion, где есть Google Play Services, какие мне очень нужны. Как исправить ? Спасибо.

Comment: мне помогло  adb shell settings put global verifier_verify_adb_installs 0

Comment: Можно подробней ?

Comment: Устанавливаете adb; и в терминале в android studio указываете эту команду